# How to find most followed account by country with TwitterAPIExchange?

Tags: php, api, twitter

I'm setting up a list of the most followed accounts by country. I'm using [TwitterAPIExchange](https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php/blob/master/TwitterAPIExchange.php) but I don't find the right API.

I've found the following API but I can't manage it properly:
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/geo/place-information/overview

Can you help me?

```
$url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/geo/id/df51dec6f4ee2b2c.json";

$requestMethod = "GET";

$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
$response = $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
         ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
         ->performRequest();

$string = json_decode($response, true);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($string);
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot think of a way to do this, using that API method or any other. The `geo/id` API returns information such as the name and location (and coordinates or bounding box) of a place, and that will not help you.

The issue here is that you want to do two things:
- search users by geo
- filter users by most followers

There is no geo search for users on Twitter, and even if there were, a user's geo (profile location) is a free-form field, so you can, for example, set your location to "The Moon" which is obviously not a location or country on Earth, so such a search could be very inaccurate.

In short, there are no API functions that will directly help you, it will be a very manual piece of work.